# How to view file actions (reads and writes) during a CI build on Github Actions?

Tags: linux, docker, file, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to track the file actions (reads and writes) (by using *strace* or *inotifywait*) performed by different steps of a job on a continuous integration workflow in Github Actions.

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Maven resolve ranges
    run: ./mvnw versions:resolve-ranges -ntp -Dincludes='org.springframework:*,org.springframework.boot:*'

  - name: Cache Maven Repos
    uses: actions/cache@v2
    with:
      path: ~/.m2/repository
      key: ${{ runner.os }}-maven-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
      restore-keys: |
        ${{ runner.os }}-maven-

  - name: Set up JDK 8
    uses: actions/setup-java@v2
    with:
      distribution: 'temurin'
      java-version: 8

  - name: Build with Maven
    run: echo y | ./mvnw -B --no-transfer-progress clean install -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -Drat.skip=true -Dcheckstyle.skip=true -Dspotless.apply.skip=true

  - name: Build examples with Maven
    run: echo y | ./mvnw -B -f examples/pom.xml clean package -DskipTests
```

As an illustration, in the example above, there are 6 steps, and I would like to keep track of file actions performed by each of them separately.

I believe I have two options;

1. Tracking file actions in Github Servers
2. Tracking file actions in my PC

In the first option, I probably have to write a plugin and add it to the workflow so that it can watch file actions on GitHub servers, and in the latter option, the challenge is simulating the workflow locally.

I found a tool ([nektos/act](https://github.com/nektos/act)) however, this tool simulates the workflow inside a docker container, so I am not sure if I can watch file actions inside a docker container.

Do you have any suggestions on which path I should follow?

Comment: Why do you need to watch all file actions?

Comment: By using the file actions, I am planning to analyze whether certain files/folders are created unnecessarily.